# In angular code, foreach loop skips to the other function before finishing the loop iteration

Tags: angular, for-loop, foreach, async-await, iteration

```js
private  processArray(evts: Event[]): Promise<void> {
  var auditsvc = this.auditSvc;
  var t = this;

  if(!evts || evts.length ==0 ) {
    return;
  }
  let objArr: any[] = [];

  evts.forEach( function (inpEvt) {   

      auditsvc.getAuditDetails(inpEvt.id).subscribe((data) => {
        
        for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          let outObj = {};
          
          outObj['Driver'] = inpEvt.driver.name;
          outObj['Executive'] = inpEvt.executive.exec.name;
          outObj['Point of Departure'] = inpEvt.pod;
          outObj['Date of Departure'] = UtilService.dateToString(inpEvt.date);
          outObj['Arrival Time'] = UtilService.timeToString(inpEvt.arrivalTime);
          outObj['Departure Time'] = UtilService.timeToString(inpEvt.departureTime);   
          outObj['Action Timestamp'] = data[i].actionedOnTimestamp;         
          outObj['Modified By'] = data[i].modifiedBy;
          outObj['Comment'] = data[i].comment;
          

          objArr.push(outObj);
          
          
        }    
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }, () => {
       
      });
  });

  if(objArr.length == 0) {
    UtilService.openError(t.modalSvc,'No logs found.');
    return;
  }else{
    t.exportAsXLSX(objArr);
  }
}
```

the for each loop is not executed but the next function is executed first. I want the loop to iterate first and then go to the other function as the loop returns some data required by the other function.

Since the loop is not iterated, the objArr length is 0, it always gives 'No logs found' error.

Comment: You have there a subscription, which is async, so the code runs over it (even though it does complete the loop at some point). Try moving your length check somewhere esle, probably earlier, or do it when the loop reaches the last item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `auditsvc.getAuditDetails()` is an async operation, so `evts.forEach` simply iterates over `evts`, registers the subscriptions—putting them on an async queue—then exits. The `subscribe` callback functions won't get called until sometime later, after the async operations have completed, and after your current code has already checked `objArr.length`.

What you need to do is build a pipeline in which `objArr.length` is checked *after* all async operations have completed and populated `objArr`.

One way to do that would be to create an array of Observables by mapping each `inpEvt` in `evts` to a corresponding Observable that gets its audit details, like this:

```js
const auditDetails$: Observable<any>[] = evts.map(inpEvt => {
  return auditsvc.getAuditDetails(inpEvt.id).pipe(
    map(data => ({ inpEvt, data })) // <-- need to pass inpEvt also because outObj will need it
  );
});
```

You can then pass that array of Observables to RxJS [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to trigger them all and return their results in an array:

```js
forkJoin(auditDetails$).pipe( // <-- auditDetails$ is array of Observables
  map((auditDetails: any[]) => { // <-- auditDetails is array of all Observable results, here passed to RxJS map operator
  })
)
```

You can then use the RxJS [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator to transform the audit details data into the `objArr` you need.

To do that, inside the RxJS `map` projection function you can just use native JavaScript [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the array of audit details to the array of `outObj`s, like so:

```js
forkJoin(auditDetails$).pipe(
  map((auditDetails: any[]) => { // <-- RxJS map operator
    return auditDetails.map(({ inpEvt, data }) => { // <-- native JS Array#map
      const outObj = {};

      for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        
        outObj['Driver'] = inpEvt.driver.name;
        // ......
        outObj['Comment'] = data[i].comment;
      }

      return outObj;
    });
  })
)
```

Finally, subscribe to that Observable pipe and you'll get the `objArr` in the fully-populated state you need it in:

```js
forkJoin(auditDetails$).pipe(
  map((auditDetails: any[]) => {
    // ...
  })
).subscribe(objArr => { // <-- final result is asynchronously-populated objArr
  if (objArr.length == 0) {
    UtilService.openError(t.modalSvc,'No logs found.');
    return;
  } else {
    t.exportAsXLSX(objArr);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow thats great!
It worked for me! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear. If you feel that it answers your question, please [accept it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so others with the same or similar question can see there's an answer.